# Adding a new domain to my VPS not working (CentOS/Apache)

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, httpd, domain-registrar

What I'm trying to do is to add a new domain to my VPS.
So I added a new domain to my httpd.conf and updated the corresponding nameservers on my registrar.

I used this code in httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin emanuel@*****.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.ro  
    ServerName www.example.ro 
    ServerAlias example.ro 
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.ro/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.ro/requests.log common

       <Directory /var/www/example.ro>
          <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
           Options -MultiViews
           RewriteEngine On
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
           RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
          </IfModule>
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I waited a day to make sure that the dns propagation is okay but it seems like the domain is not bound to any dns. When I try to ping the domain name, I get " Ping request cound not find host example.ro. Please check the name and try again ".

Am I missing something? I'm a beginner in server configurations

Comment: In your description above, you're missing the step "configure the name servers".

Comment: I configured the name servers by adding a subdomain pointing to the IP of my VPS.

Comment: You must have missed something when you did that. Did you remember to update the serial number of the zone? Otherwise, the changes won't take effect.

Comment: Unfortunately, people here thinks your question isn't about servers. I would suggest to re-ask this on http://unix.stackexchange.com, where it will have probably much better chance to survive.

Comment: Run `dig +trace example.ro` to see what's going on. Also if the question is about DNS, keep it short and don't mix it with HTTP (Apache) issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your error message is " Ping request cound not find host domain.ro. Please check the name and try again " the error does not lie with your apache configuration. The nameservers hosting your domain is not reporting any A-record for your domain (assuming the DNS-client you are trying to ping from is working correctly).

Start by looking if a nslookup for your domain reports any Nameservers. If they do, look next at the DNS-records the nameserver reports. I personally use http://centralops.net which will give you all this information by just entering the domain name in the search field, and it will also bypass any possible dns-client configuration errors on your end.